# How do I get a 4-digit year from fakerjs date.birthdate() when setting `max` and `min`

Tags: javascript, date, faker.js

I'm trying to use the community fakerjs library to [get a random birthdate](https://fakerjs.dev/api/date.html#birthdate). I want it to be within the last 70 years at the latest. In my output, though, I keep getting years like `79` and `12` instead of `1979` or `2012`. I can only get a 2-digit year.

```js
let date = faker.date.birthdate({ max: 70, min: 1 });
// 0037-08-27T13:35:09.312Z
date.getFullYear()
// 37
```

`.birthdate()` by itself works fine, it's just when I use `max` and `min` that the problem shows up.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There's no bug, I just wasn't reading the docs correctly. I assumed `faker.date.birthdate({ max: 70, min: 1 })` would understand `70` and `1` to be ages, but the method by default thinks they're actually years, so it's imagining that I want anything between the year `0001` and the year `0070`.

I needed to add `mode: 'age'` to the options:

```js
let date = faker.date.birthdate({ max: 70, min: 1, mode: 'age' });
// 1965-02-05T20:58:06.207Z
date.getFullYear()
// 1965
```

By default, `mode` is set to `year`.